# How do I refer to a word using all variations, no matter the size of the letters within the words?

Tags: notepad++, uppercase, lowercase

Alright, so I am making a Discord bot, and I'm trying to set parameters for words that aren't allowed to be said in the server (You know the kind, slurs and the like). So, I put a slur (I'll just use the word "dog" as an example), but it was only lowercase. So basically, it's just "dog", and if someone says "dog" in chat, then their message will be deleted, and the bot sends them a message through DMs. But, if someone were to say "Dog", then they wouldn't get their message deleted.  What should I add to the code to make sure that all variations of the slur get picked up?

I'm incredibly new to any form of coding, and I have gotten a ton of help from my friends to make this bot, so I really have no clue about what I'm doing.

(if you want to see the code, here it is.  I replaced all the slurs with words, but I think you get the gist):

```
   "bannedWords":[
       "apple",
      "dog",
      "bird",
      "cat"
   ],
   "code":""
}
```

I expect the words "dog", "Dog", "DOg", "DOG", "dOG", "doG", "DoG", "dOg", etc. to be identified instead of just "dog".

Comment: Consider .toLowerCase() or .toLower() . When called on a string this will make all the characters lowercase.

Comment: As you probably assume, listing all the variants is tedious and impractical, so you really want some code to unify them. Unfortunately, discord bots are written in any number of languages, using any number of frameworks, and we have no clue which one you're using, which makes this question as answerable as "how do I feed my pet correctly" without telling us whether it's a Python, a Chicken, or a Julia.

Comment: What does Notepad++ have to do with your question?  What language/tool are you actually using?

Comment: The language is JSON, for those who are asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a very complex question.
The most simple approach would be creating an array of banned words on lower-case and comparing it to the string after manipulating it completely to lower cause using something like .toLower() or .toLowerCase() in JavaScript.
But that wouldn't stop from users trying to bypass your list by using similar characters and even ASCII characters as a replacement, like dög, d0g or even døg.
Solving that actually is the complex part of the question.
One option is using Regex wildcards like  the . operator.

```
\d.g\
Will match dog, dög....
```

But that would be very impractical and time consuming, not to mention the computational cost if your banned list is long.
There are several ways on how this could be accomplished, the easiest ones, like described above would suit just fine some friends-only-server as you just described, but in situations where the detection of those words are critical, using [Stemming](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) Algorithms, [Fuzzy Matching](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_matching_(computer-assisted_translation)), Regular Expressions and Machine Learning like described in [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-better-profanity-detection-library-with-scikit-learn-3638b2f2c4c2?gi=5b0b67764e63) article, are all valid options and optimal if combined with each other efficiently.